# RS232 Serial - USB Converter device path (/dev/ttyUSB*) not getting listed

Tags: python, ruby, usb, serial-port

I am using an RS232 Serial - USB Converter to connect to a controller. I am  trying to connect to this port programmatically.

The device is getting listed as below when I give **lsusb**

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 05ad:0fba Y.C. Cable U.S.A., Inc.
```

But I am not able to see it's device path (something like /dev/ttyUSB*).

I would like to know the way to get the path from device id (or) a way to create / find the path which can be used to open the port from a program (Ruby, Python, C)

Comment: What operating system are you running and what distribution/version? Sounds like the chipset on the dongle is unsupported by your kernel if no device node is showing up.

Comment: I am using CentOS release 5.6 (Final).

Answer (score 0):

Centos has a fairly old kernel. It may be lacking in support for your device.

Are you able to try with a newer distribution (Fedora, Ubuntu, etc) to test whether it works or not? Failing that, do you have a different dongle you can use?

You can Google for "Centos 05ad:0fba" or similar combinations to find out whether it's supported.